# Specific SD card not detected in a specific phone

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage

So, I had an SD card (16GB). It works normally on my phone. I put it on PC to transfer some files, and now my phone doesn't detect it being inserted.

- other phones detect this SD card normally
- pc detect this SD card normally
- my phone detects other SD cards normally
- my phone can read the SD through OTG
- the SD card filesystem is fat32 normally.

So, what is going on? Why would my phone **no longer** accept this one SD specifically?

Comment: The most problematic weakness of SD-cards is the physical connection between card reader and card. If the card and/or the reader do not fit 100% together an electrical contact may be not working correctly. Check the card carefully if it has scratches on the contacts and compare it to other cards if something seems to be different.

Comment: @Robert , the card is physically fine. It's new and it works on other devices normally. Just this phone is not detecting it.